# Serilog and ASP.NET Core enrich `WithUserName` and `WithHttpRequestUserAgent`?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, serilog, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1, asp.net-core-logging

Is there a way to enrich `Serilog` log data in ASP.NET Core 2.1 application, similar to how enrichers `WithUserName`and `WithHttpRequestUserAgent` work for classic ASP.NET (`System.Web`)?

I tried implementing `ILogEventEnricher` interface, but it does not work, because I am not able to gain access to `RequestContext` from my custom enricher.

Comment: See [Enrichment](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment) and in your middleware use `LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.User.Identity.Name)`.

Comment: @MarkG I was playing with this a bit and made it working, but I wonder if there can be threading issues? This is remark about `LogContext` says: "The scope of the context is the current logical thread, using AsyncLocal (and so is preserved across async/await calls).", so I wonder if it is safe to assume that `HttpRequest` is always bound to 1 logical thread?

Comment: I'm left wondering the exact same thing. The Serilog documentation in this area is not at all good.

Comment: Does this point you in the right direction? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261177/add-username-into-serilog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Username into Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261177/add-username-into-serilog)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments it seems like  [Add Username into Serilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51261177/add-username-into-serilog) would serve your purpose and would also be the duplicate of this issue.